# What does the DragCompletedGestureEventArgs.Velocity parameter mean exactly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

The `DragCompleted` event of a wp7 control has a parameter of type `DragCompletedGestureEventArgs` that contains the variables `HorizontalVelocity` and `VerticalVelocity`.

How are these velocity variables interpreted? I get a value of 0 for a slow drag and a value of >4000 for a fast drag, but I'm not sure how I can relate these numbers into a *number of pixels dragged per time interval* value.

Background of my question: In my program the user can grab an object and then drag it. I want the object to continue moving (up to a standstill) when the user lets go of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't relate them into pixels. But you can create a relative scale according to the velocity, and then how much it should slow down / speed up, based on the velocity.

If you think of the Pictures Hub image viewer, then you can see that you can pan around images, but if you use a high enough velocity, it'll flick to the next/previous image.